# Is there a shortcut for self.assertNotEqual() in nose?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

`_eq` seems to be the equal to `self.assertEqual()`

But is there also a `self.assertNotEqual()` in nose?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nose doesn't have an equivalent to `self.assertNotEqual()`, but you can use all of the `unittest.TestCase` assert methods via `nose.tools`. They are renamed to all-lowercase and with underscores. For example:

```
>>> from nose.tools import assert_not_equal
>>> assert_not_equal(1, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 518, in assertNotEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 1 == 1
```

[More info here.](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html?highlight=assert_equal)

Comment: How could they miss that? :)  Thanks though

Comment: Try this: `from nose.tools import assert_not_equal as neq_`